# Generic custom stream insertion operator for enums with 'fmt' library

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, name-lookup, fmt

I suspect the answer to this is fairly obvious, but it's eluding me for some reason.

I'm trying to get the `fmt` library to use a generic stream insertion operator for enum types. `fmt` formats enums as integers by default, but will also use overloaded insertion operators for user-defined types if available (in some cases at least).

To experiment, I started without using `fmt`, with this:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class Enum0 { a, b, c, };

namespace foo {

enum class Enum1 { a, b, c, };

}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>, std::ostream &>
operator<<(std::ostream & stream, T const value) {
    return stream << static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(value);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << Enum0::b << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo::Enum1::c << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

This uses a custom operator with standard output streams (with the operator commented out, it fails to compile, as expected). In this case, the operator is correctly selected for `foo::Enum1` even though the operator isn't defined in the `foo` namespace.

Then I did the same thing, but added `fmt`:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <type_traits>

#include "fmt/format.h"
#include "fmt/ostream.h"

enum class Enum0 { a, b, c, };

namespace foo {

enum class Enum1 { a, b, c, };

}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>, std::ostream &>
operator<<(std::ostream & stream, T const value) {
    return stream << "custom operator: "
        << static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(value);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << Enum0::b << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo::Enum1::c << std::endl;

    fmt::print("{}\n", Enum0::b);
    fmt::print("{}\n", foo::Enum1::c);
}
```

Output:

```
custom operator: 1
custom operator: 2
custom operator: 1
2
```

`fmt` selects the custom operator for the enum that's in the global namespace, but doesn't select the custom operator for the enum in namespace `foo`.

If I put the operator in the same namespace as the enum:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <type_traits>

#include "fmt/format.h"
#include "fmt/ostream.h"

namespace foo {

enum class Enum1 { a, b, c, };

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>, std::ostream &>
operator<<(std::ostream & stream, T const value) {
    return stream << "custom operator: "
        << static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(value);
}

}

int main() {
    std::cout << foo::Enum1::c << std::endl;

    fmt::print("{}\n", foo::Enum1::c);
}
```

I get:

```
custom operator: 2
custom operator: 2
```

Showing that `fmt` selects the overload in that case. This isn't of much use though, because the overload is intended to be a generic solution, and different enums may be in different namespaces.

What seems to be a similar issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/391). Two solutions are offered. One is to put the overload in the `std` namespace. This works, but the [rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std) surrounding that are fairly strict, and it's not immediately obvious to me that this particular use case would be valid. The other solution in the thread involves putting the operator before the `fmt` inclusions. I tried that as well:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>, std::ostream &>
operator<<(std::ostream & stream, T const value) {
    return stream << "custom operator: "
        << static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<T>>(value);
}

#include "fmt/format.h"
#include "fmt/ostream.h"

enum class Enum0 { a, b, c, };

namespace foo {

enum class Enum1 { a, b, c, };

}

int main() {
    std::cout << Enum0::b << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo::Enum1::c << std::endl;

    fmt::print("{}\n", Enum0::b);
    fmt::print("{}\n", foo::Enum1::c);
}
```

But although it seems to have worked for participants in the thread, for me, `fmt` still didn't select the overload. (I think the thread was from before default formatting of enums as integers was added to the library, so this behavior may have changed since then.)

Is there a way (other than placing the implementation in the `std` namespace) to implement a single, generic `<<` operator for enum types that will be used by `fmt`, even when the operator is in the global namespace and the enum is in another namespace? I realize there may be an extremely obvious answer here having to do with lookup rules or similar, but if there's a solution, I'm missing it, so I thought I'd ask here. (I'm aware that specializing `fmt::formatter` is another option for enum formatting, but I'm interested in whether a generic solution using `<<` is possible.)

Comment: The rule says: "It is allowed to add template specializations for any standard library function template to the namespace std only if the declaration depends on at least one program-defined type and the specialization satisfies all requirements for the original template, except where such specializations are prohibited. " .   Your case fits the requirements for the exceptional case.  It also fits the C++20 requirements.

I think you should avoid declaring the overload in the shared headers of a library, though.

Comment: @Michaël Roy: Thanks for your reply. I read that excerpt, but was unsure about it because the specialization isn't for a specific program-defined type, but rather for a category of program-defined types. But I'll keep what you said in mind and see if I can make myself comfortable with the 'namespace std' solution :-) (As for declaring the overload in a shared header, I have no intention of doing that. Any direct or indirect reference to that in my post was just by way of example.)

Comment: Yes.  As long as that addition is private to your program or library, you're fine.  It is when a library publicly exports such an overload, that you enter UB territory, and that's understandable, since it would be adding behavior to the std namepace that the end user would not expect.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy How does this meet the C++20 requiurements? "It is undefined behavior to declare a full specialization of any standard library function template.".

Comment: @Spencer: Since there is no code declared in the std namespace in the code above,  I don't see what you are talking about.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy  OP proposed putting something in `namespace std` and you commented on it.